# dnspython 1.11.1 EmptyLabel exception in python 2.7.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, dnspython

I just installed dnspython using "pip install dnspython".  I then opened up a python shell and tried the following code:

```
import dns.resolver
answers = dns.resolver.query('dnspython.org', 'MX')
```

and am immediately getting the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "dns/resolver.py", line 973, in query
    return get_default_resolver().query(qname, rdtype, rdclass, tcp, source,
  File "dns/resolver.py", line 961, in get_default_resolver
    default_resolver = Resolver()
  File "dns/resolver.py", line 489, in __init__
    self.read_resolv_conf(filename)
  File "dns/resolver.py", line 540, in read_resolv_conf
    self.search.append(dns.name.from_text(suffix))
  File "dns/name.py", line 638, in from_text
    raise EmptyLabel
dns.name.EmptyLabel
```

I am on OSX Mavericks using python 2.7.6, pip version 1.5.4, and dnspython version 1.11.1

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might have some DNS issues locally or permissions issue. Can you make sure you have your network DNS pages setup correctly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!  Turns out that my VPN had an improper domain in the settings